# outpaint/inpaint Algorithm which follows the image structure

Tags: image, image-processing

Are there algorithms for extending / outfilling images.

For example starting from.

[image: Stripy Blob] or [image]

Obtain something like

[image: Extended Stripy Blob] or [image]

Here the input consists of an source image and a mask indicating where the image should be extended.

These examples where generated using opencv2's inpaint function ( `INPAINT_TELEA` ). However this seems to extend in the direction of the boundary regardless of what is inside the images.

*Question* Is there a similar algorithm which tries to extend an image based on its content? The desired ( but likely not perfectly achievable ) result would be that the hatches are extended in the correct direction. Or more generally that hard edges and gradients at the edge are extended in the correct direction.

Wrong
[image: extension wrong]

Correct
[image: extension correct]

The red white border should not be extended perpendicular to the border but should instead follow the direction add the border